# Android: GridView Pull-To-Refresh - Override the animation?

Tags: java, android, gridview, pull-to-refresh, swiperefreshlayout

So I implemented a Pull-to-Refresh on my GridView using android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout and it works well. But when dragging down the finger, only the animation plays and the 'GridView-being-pulled-down-animation' doesn't happen like it should when refreshing. The GridView stays intact while it gets updated. How can I override this animation method and add a GridView movement which clearly shows the animation where the GridView gets pulled down with the finger's movement? (similar to facebook, instagram's refresh)

**And also maybe display a message at the top saying 'Refreshing'**

My Code so far.

**XML:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ECECEC"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/feed_item_padding_top_bottom" >

               <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                  android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/grid"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:columnWidth="100dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:numColumns="1"
                    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
            </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Code:**

```
swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {

            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                //my update process
                RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
                params.put("req", "dataReqAndroid");
                invokeWS(params);
            }
        });
        swipeLayout.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright, 
                android.R.color.holo_green_light, 
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light, 
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);
```